# When using an empty list as a default value for a constructor function, this list becomes a reference - why? Is this a bug?

Tags: python, pointers, object

This is a more a question to gain an understanding.
Consider the code below

```
class MenuItem:
    def __init__(self, title, children = []):
        self.title = title
        self.children = children

item1 = MenuItem('A')
item2 = MenuItem('B')
item2.children.append('C')
print (item1.children)
```

When run with either python2 or python3:

```
python test.py                                           [~]
['C']
```

In this case, the children for an object, defaults to the empty list. `children = []`. However, if I create two objects, they share the same children list.

I understand that object based types are just a pointer to a more complex object etc, but I don't understand what exactly `[]` is pointing to. If I change `item2.title`, that has no effect on `item1.title`.

If I change the default item to `['X']` for example, I get `item1.children = ['X', 'C']`

Could someone please explain this behaviour.

Thanks

Anthony

note: The solution is simply to say `children = False` and `self.children = (children if children else []` which then works as expected - I'm just wondering why the behaviour is as above.

Comment: Congratulations on coming up with a *realistic* example of the problem. I've been frustrated by most examples of this problem, because they're always in a context that just doesn't make sense. In your case I think the proper solution is to *always* make a *copy* of whatever list is passed in, whether it's the default or not.

Comment: In reply to your title: Parameters in Python are always passed by reference, but there are mutable and immutable objects, which is what makes the difference.

Comment: Cheers, my main question what that clearly item1.children and item2.children pointed at the same object, just wasn't sure what.

Having read through the duplicate, think I understand.

When the function `MenuItem.__init__` is defined, the array `[]` is created and stored as `MenuItem.__init__.__defaults__[0]`

Now when a function inherits the default value, what happens is `chilren = MenuItem.__init__.__defaults__[0]`.

My confusion came as I thought that `children = []` would be evaluated when the function was called, rather than being evaluated when the function was defined and then stored.